# X-macro Substitution in C++

Tags: c++, qt, macros

I have used X-macros a lot in C but seem to be having an issue using this one with C++ and Qt.  I am using the X-macro to synchronize some names with some strings in a couple projects.  In one project I only need to generate a "const char* const NAME = STRING;" value and an external reference to that constant in a ".h" file: "extern const char* const NAME;". I am getting an undefined reference to my NAME when I compile the project.  This is what I have in my "XML_Keywords.h" file to define the X-macros.

```
#define SELECT_KEYWORD(a, b) a,                             
#define SELECT_STRING(a, b) b,                             
#define SELECT_GEN_CONST(KEY, STR) const char* const KEY = STR; 
#define SELECT_EXT_CONST(KEY, STR) extern const char* const KEY;

#define FOR_UNIT_KEYWORDS(apply)                              \
    apply(UNIT_NAME_STR, "UnitNameStr" )                      \
    apply(UNIT_CODE_STR, "UnitCodeStr" )                      \
    apply(UNIT_HDWR_ID,  "UnitHdwrID"  )
```

In my "Keywords.cpp" file I do this to expand into a series of "const char* const" declarations.

```
#include "XML_Keywords.h" 

FOR_UNIT_KEYWORDS(SELECT_GEN_CONST)
```

And in my "Keywords.h" file I do this to expand into my extern defintions.

```
#include "XML_Keywords.h" 

FOR_UNIT_KEYWORDS(SELECT_EXT_CONST)
```

I include the "Keywords.h" in my other .cpp files where needed but I keep getting an undefined reference for UNIT_NAME_STR, UNIT_CODE_STR and UNIT_HDWR_ID.  I cannot track down my error.  Thanks.

Comment: Does it link if you put in what you expect the macros to expand to directly?

Comment: Check that you are actually compiling and linking `Keywords.cpp`. Perhaps it's simply not added to your build.

Comment: @chris, yes, I had explicit defines to start.  In another project I need the same pairs for an enum and string list.

Comment: Igor, yes, it is my .pro file and it is being compiled and linked

Comment: OK, I went back and changed it back to explicit defines and its still broken so somehow I broke something else.  I need to find that.  Sorry, it worked before I started the change to the macros.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, for anyone else that is a C programmer but now doing C++ the way constants are handled is very different.  I found out that the reason my code worked with the explicit **const** definitions in the **keyword.cpp** file was that I also included **keyword.h** file in the **keyword.cpp** file which defined those constants as **extern**.  When the **h** file was not included in the **cpp** file the constants were not exported even though the other files that used the constants did import the **h** file.  This is totally different from C. After reading up more, it seems the constants should be put in the **h** file and there should be no **cpp** file at all.